# How do I reset my SMTP password?

Tags: google-chrome, email, passwords, thunderbird, smtp

After working for about three weeks, I finally got back the Thunderbird account that I thought was lost. Everything is fine except sending emails. Every time I send an email, a password is requested from me. I enter the correct password, but it is rejected. I check for the saved password inside Thunderbird, but there is no listing for the SMTP server. About one out of 15 attempts is successful. When I check for the saved password, it is there. But the next time I try to send an email, I am asked for the password again.

I believe the possibility exists that somewhere some obscure setting has been poorly configured. That or I continue to chase my tail around this problem.

Windows 10 PRO, Google Chrome, Thunderbird 98.7.0 (32 bit)

Comment: @moab Apologies, but you are not correct here - SMTP Auth is a protocol used which makes use of a password as part of the SMTP protocol.  This is usually (but not neccessarily) handled by other software tied into your SMTP server.

Comment: Does your thunderbird have multiple accounts?  It is possible that most of the time authentication is failing against one account, but sometimes a different account is being used for sending and SMTP authentication works on that account.

Comment: Moab - This is the password that I use to allow the SMTP server to pass my email to the internet.  Point taken.

Comment: davidgo - I have only one account using Thunderbird.

Comment: You may want to consider trying to delete any `pkcs11.txt` file in your profile as suggested in this [Thunderbird FAQ](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_not_remembered_-_Thunderbird) regarding passwords.